# Django filter by a specific day

Tags: django, date, filter

I have an application that I need to pick one day and it returns me the total number of events as well as the list of active events that day.
Each event has a duration.
I can filter for today, but how do I do if I want to filter for any other day?

model

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Name')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='Start')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='End')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

view

```
def total_events(request):
    events = Event.objects.filter(Q(start_date__lte=timezone.now()) & Q(end_date__gte=timezone.now()))
    total_events = events.count()
    context = {
        'events': events,
        'total_events': total_events,
    }

    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Event Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
DAY:
<input type="text">
<button>Filter</button>
<br>
<br>
<b>Total of active events in filtered day:</b> {{ total_events }}
<br>
<b>List of active events in filtered day:</b>
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for event in events %}
            <td>
                {{ event.name }}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is like this:

[image]

Can some one give me a direction to follow? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a `datetime` object for the day you want to filter.

```
day = timezone.datetime(year=2019, month=11, day=30)

# and now you can use this object in your filter query
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging i found this solution:

views

```
def total_events(request):
    events = Event.objects.all()
    day_query = request.GET.get('day')
    if day_query != '' and day_query is not None:
        events = Event.objects.filter(Q(start_date__date__lte=day_query) & Q(end_date__date__gte=day_query))

    total_events = events.count()

    context = {
        'events': events,
        'total_events': total_events,
    }

    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Event Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
DAY:
<form method="GET" action=".">
    <input type="text" name="day">
    <button type="submit">Filter</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<b>Total of active events in filtered day:</b> {{ total_events }}
<br>
<b>List of active events in filtered day:</b>
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for event in events %}
            <td>
                {{ event.name }}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```